# What’s the Ethdev contract and what’s the purpose?

Tags: parity-wallet

Everything is in the title : What’s it’s purpose ; The addresses paid with this contract belong to who ?

Additionally, [since it’s ᴀʙɪ is public](https://etherscan.io/address/0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae#code), is it the same for it’s exact source (I already guess it’s parity multisig) ?

Answer (score 5):

It's the Ethereum Foundation's multisig account which manages the holdings collected initially by the foundation.

first implementation can be found here : https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol

Comment: The addresses paid with this contract belong to who ? About the source code, I thought solidity version and compiler options was an obvious question…